# Определения подходящего диапазона цвета на маске

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, mask

[image: Оригинальный кадр, извините за другой ракурс]я попробовал создать диапазон цвета на маске для оранжевого цвета(справа), чтобы не выделялся красный(слева). Но у меня возникают такие неточности из-за того, что цвета схожи, помогите[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def nothing(*arg):
        passcv2.namedWindow("result")  # создаем главное окноcv2.namedWindow("settings")  # создаем окно настроекcap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# создаем 6 бегунков для настройки начального и конечного цвета фильтраcv2.createTrackbar('h1', 'settings', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('s1', 'settings', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('v1', 'settings', 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('h2', 'settings', 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('s2', 'settings', 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('v2', 'settings', 255, 255, nothing)
crange = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

while True:
    flag, img = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # считываем значения бегунков    h1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('h1', 'settings')
    s1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('s1', 'settings')
    v1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('v1', 'settings')
    h2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('h2', 'settings')
    s2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('s2', 'settings')
    v2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('v2', 'settings')

    # формируем начальный и конечный цвет фильтра    h_min = np.array((h1, s1, v1), np.uint8)
    h_max = np.array((h2, s2, v2), np.uint8)

    # накладываем фильтр на кадр в модели HSV    thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv, h_min, h_max)

    cv2.imshow('result', thresh)

    ch = cv2.waitKey(5)
    if ch == 27:
        breakcap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4K0X.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4K0X.jpg)

Comment: Оригинальную картинку не добавите в вопрос?

Comment: Добавил, посмотрите пожалуйста @Amgarak

Comment: Думаю тут без вариантов, у вас диапазон цветов пересекается в обоих кубиках. Разве что искать сами объекты и анализировать их. К примеру мы нашли 2 кубика(по контуру например), если в одном пикселей определенного диапазона цветов больше, то выбираем его... но с таким увы не помогу. В целом вообще чего добиться хотите?